# Why Apache's <Files> directive keeps giving me error 500?

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess

This directive in .htaccess:

```
<Files wp-config.php>  
order allow,deny  
deny from all 
</Files>
```

Gives me error 500. Ave you maybe got some good idea about?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Two possibilities jump to mind:

First, usually I see the filename quoted: `<Files "wp-config.php">`.  I forget whether Apache requires quotes or not, so try this and see if that fixes the problem.

Second, your Apache server administrator may not have enabled the required `AllowOverride` permissions to allow you to do this.

In either case, checking the Apache error logs will reveal the true problem.